# Getting Number of records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Am trying to fetch the number of records in the table using Count(*) along with my query condition
Sample Table is
Table: STUD_NAME

```
Id Name  
1  Steven  
2  smith  
2  Ben  
1  Willy
```

My query is

```
 select std.name 
 from STUD_Name where id='2'
```

for this it will display the output as "Smith" and "Ben", along with i need the total number of records in the STUD_NAME table.

By right it should display the total records as "4", please help me out to solve this issue and how to form the query in this case

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, 
       cnt as total_count
FROM (
    SELECT id
           name,
           count(*) over () as cnt
    FROM stud_name
) t
WHERE id = 2
```

Assuming that `id` is a numeric column the single quotes around the value `2` are not needed (and are actually harmful due to the implicit data type conversion that happens in the background)

Comment: Hi again some problem in my query, I need to display the count according to my where condition, "select STUD_NAME.name, from STUD_NAME where id='2', I need to display name which matched to id "2" + no of rows which fetched for id'2', its bid priority pls help me out

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select 
       std.name 
      ,(select count(1) from STUD_Name) nrofstds  
from   STUD_Name std where std.id='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select STUD_NAME.name, CNT.count
from STUD_NAME
   , (select count(*) COUNT from STUD_NAME) CNT
where id='2'
```

Comment: Hi again some problem in my query, I need to display the count according to my where condition, "select STUD_NAME.name, from STUD_NAME where id='2', I need to display name which matched to id "2" + no of rows which fetched for id'2', its bid priority pls help me out